# 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable typeerror

Tags: django

I want to get all profiles that the user is following and display them in separate div with(img, name,email). I can get the total number of 'following', however, I'm not able to iterate throw following and display user by user.

```
Exception Value:    

'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

Any help is appreciated!

dashboard:

```
  <p>{{ user.following.count }}</p>

        {% for guest in user.following %}
        <div class="container-videos-card">
            <div class="videos-card-details">
                <h4 class = "container-videos-card-title">{{ guest.email }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>  
      {% endfor %}
```

model:

```
   class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null = False)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=264, null = True, blank = True)
        
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null = True,  blank = True)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=264, null = True, blank = True)
        profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    
    class Follow(models.Model):
        follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
        following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
```

Comment: Use user.following.all

Comment: but I can access only that table with pk, follower_id, following_id. How can I access other properties like Profile username, profile_picture?

Comment: `guest.profile.profile_picture`?